# Getting run-time error 75 when renaming and moving the file

Tags: vba

Getting Run-time error when i try to move a file. The file is in my documents, and within documents there is a folder called "**Archive**", which is where im trying to move. As you can see in the last part of the code, I've added the text "Archive" to the file path so that there is a new file path. Can someone explain why this error occurs?

```
Public wb As Workbook
Public ws As Worksheet
Public SourceFile_Location
Public srcWB As String
Public srcWB_sheet As String
```

```
Sub Full_Code()
Call DataFile
Call test2
End Sub
```

```
Sub DataFile()

SourceFile_Location = Dir("C:\Users\Asad\Documents\*.xl??")

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(SourceFile_Location)
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

srcWB = wb.Name
srcWB_sheet = ws.Name

End Sub
```

```
Sub test2()
wb.Activate

fpath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
fpathnew = fpath & "\Archive"

ActiveWorkbook.Close

Name fpath As fpathnew & "\" & srcWB ***<- this is where my error is***

End Sub
```

Comment: You have `Sub test2()` and `Sub Full_Code()` with only one `End Sub`.

Comment: You may want to read up on [Path/File access error (Error 75)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/path-file-access-error-error-75). Having said that, check the values of `fpathnew` and `srcWB`. And yes, one more thing... Definitely read [to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). Your code can be made more robust. ;)

Comment: here is why the error occurs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/path-file-access-error-error-75

Comment: Name fpath & "\" & srcWB As fpathnew & "\" & srcWB
 would solve the problem.

Comment: Please edit your question to get an answer to describe what you need, timestamp can be 158888544 in seconds, or 20210513 date of today, before file name or after file name ...?

Comment: Sorry, StackOverFLow community will not accept this kind of work, please make your own test before.  And +edit your question.